# Changing domain name and analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-tag-manager, domain-transfer

We are changing domain name but the website is staying exactly the same. We are 301 redirecting every page.

We believe that we wouldn't have to create a new property in analytics or tag manager as everything is the same but the domain name.

In Search Console would we not just use the change of address tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the entire site is exactly the same (including folder structure) and you only changed the domain name, here's what you need to do:

1. Complete the migration, make sure all 301's work properly.
2. Add and verify the new domain on Google's search console.
3. Use the change of address tool.

Read more here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en

Good luck with the new domain!

Comment: Also (assuming there aren't hostname filters set in GA), Google Analytics will continue to work normally as long as you keep sending pageview hits to the same UA-XXXXX-Y code